# Rails 4 - Error during failsafe response: undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, warden

We have a rails 4 app in production environment, on a webrick server, that crashes regularly and returns a 500 error.
The crash seems to come from the following error :

```
Error during failsafe response: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:58:in `current_user'
```

We've checked the helpers.rb file at line 58, and so it comes from a call to wardent.authenticate in the 'current_user' method. So we've imported the gem 'warden' in our Gemfile, but nothing changes.

We also tried to change the webrick server into a 'puma' server, thinking it could come from threads, but nothing changed...

The entire error is the following :

```
Error during failsafe response: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:58:in `current_user'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:53:in `current_user'
  /home/dev/myProject/app/views/shared/_top_menu.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_shared__top_menu_html_erb___3475115451092967008_67265400'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  /home/dev/myProject/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2013404122424653986_65265180'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2818342425517875908__process_action__callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:43:in `render_exception'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `rescue in call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
Error during failsafe response: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:58:in `current_user'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:53:in `current_user'
  /home/dev/myProject/app/views/shared/_top_menu.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_shared__top_menu_html_erb___3475115451092967008_68619440'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  /home/dev/myProject/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2013404122424653986_65265180'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2818342425517875908__process_action__callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:43:in `render_exception'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `rescue in call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
[2014-11-07 13:06:52] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
[2014-11-07 13:06:52] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2014-11-07 13:06:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Processing by ErrorsController#internal_server_error as HTML
  Rendered errors/internal_server_error.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_top_menu.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
```

Does anyone has an idea of where it could come from ?

**Update**

An other error happens just before the error detailed up in this post, here is the error :

```
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)):
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in wait_poll'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `loop'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `wait_poll'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:136:in `block in poll'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:146:in `synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:134:in `poll'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:423:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2890043484802466369__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.11) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Update 2**

I've added the 'puma' gem to the Gemfile to enable the puma multi-threading server, and added the following config/initializers/database_connection.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL']      || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

But the error still occurs...

**Solution !**

We've deployed an Apache Server, with Capistrano and Phusion Passenger. Since this time, everything works well, no problems with Rails, or devise, or anything else. I think the problem was we trusted the default Webrick server to work in a production environment, whereas it's intended to work only for development environments...

Thanks to all for your help and your advises

Comment: just wondering you are using webrick on a production server. Anyway, I wanted to look the following file:
/home/dev/myProject/app/views/shared/_top_menu.html.erb:23 so I can help you I guess.

Comment: The code at line 23 of _top_menu.html.erb is the following :
<% if current_user && current_user.redactor? %>

Comment: okey, this won't help me. Need more outputs. Like can you share the devise related all activities into the gists. It seems the problem is with your devise configuration. Some methods are missing.

Comment: I've added the other error that occurs just before the first in the logs.

Comment: in crease your database pool.

Comment: I've put in place a puma server, and increased the pool of connections. But still the error... I update the post to show you what I've done

Comment: @Jimmy4701 are you using your own routes to catch exceptions and redirect to a custom error page?

Comment: @monteirobrena yes we use specific routes. But all seems to work well, now we've put an apache, capistrano, passenger environment for the production. And it works well.

Comment: @Jimmy4701 I wasn't using webrick for the production environment.

Comment: Does your app by chance use a devise method (current_user for example) in a before_action in your application_controller?

Answer (score 6):

As a follow-on for people who find this error from Google. If you use Devise, this error will occur when Devise cannot initialize properly. If you watch your logs, you might find another error occurring at boot which is preventing Devise from initializing.

In my case, the root issue was that I had pending migrations.

Comment: Much appreciated. I was working on a new environment with an identical DB but with pending migrations.

Comment: Adding my experience for future Googlers: Devise will throw this error if it can't connect to your database. I was missing some env vars. I managed to run `rails c` inside the Docker container and a simple `User.count` revealed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After having installed an Apache Server + Phusion Passenger + Capistrano, and well configured the all environment for a production deploy, everything seems to work well. 
(Only a webrick server for a production env was, effectivly, a bad idea... even for a beta version)

Thanks to all who helped us and answered our questions.

Comment: webrick will do that to you, I have had good luck using `thin` https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/

Answer (score 0):

My similar problem was because I tried to capture the 404 error but I had a image with wrong mapping and was always falling in the error page until lock my project. And then I had this problem, too:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds))
```

The solution was fix the mapping and any other recurrent error like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this. This is the exact same problem i'm having.

Comment: @Catfish try disable the route to error page to verify what the error is most frequent.